# Is there a maximum amount of time that tail -f can reliably run?

Tags: command-line, apache2, log, tail

I have noticed that when I `tail -f` various log files (specifically Apache access/error logs), that it ceases to actively scroll output after a certain of number of hours.

I am uncertain if this is a problem with the `tail` command or some other issue.

Initially I suspected log rotation was to blame, but the logs are not being rotated when this occurs.

Answer (score 0):

It maybe that the log file has been renamed as part of the scheduled log rotation, so in which case tail -f is looking at the (now) old log.  Perhaps using tail -F is a better approach as this can detect when the new replacement log file appears.

Comment: As I mentioned, I have ruled out log rotation by comparing the time the rotation happens with the time tail -f starts ignoring file changes